# Tkinter very odd behaviour when using the "root.after(1000)" function

Tags: python, tkinter

in tkinter I am trying to create a stopwatch/timer and I have the basic code done however something odd happens and I have no idea how to explain it so just see this video.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ImgL.jpg
(and if just keeps on going)

Here is the code that handles the timer:

```
def TimerUpdate():
    global TimerVar
    TimerVar = TimerVar - 1
    Timer.config(text = f"{TimerVar}")
    root.after(1000, TimerUpdate)
def Update():
    global TimerOn
    now = datetime.now()
    time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    Time.config(text = f"{time}")
    if TimerOn == True:
        root.after(1000, TimerUpdate)
    else:
        root.after(1000, Update)
```

And here is the code that mentions the "TimerOn" variable

```
def Start():
    global TimerOn
    Timer.config(font = ("Times New Roman", 50))
    Timer.place(x = "160", y = "250")
    TimerOn = True
```

I am obviously trying to make it go down each second but I have no idea whats happening here.

Answer (score 0):

After `TimerOn = True` the update function checks `if TimerOn == True` and since it's `True` it keeps calling the `TimerUpdate` function every time. Try making `TimerOn = False` after calling `TimerUpdate`:

```py
if TimerOn == True:
    root.after(1000, TimerUpdate)
    TimerOn = False
else:
    root.after(1000, Update)
```